# cannot run behat's locally "cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: BASE_URL (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException)"

Tags: symfony, guzzle, behat

I'm running Behats locally in my Symfony 2.8 app via the command line. Each scenario fails with the error "cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: BASE_URL (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException)"

in app/config/parameters.yml I've tried changing

```
   base_url: http://BASE_URL
```

to my local path

```
   base_url: 'http://127.0.0.1/myapp/web/app_dev.php'
```

or 'localhost', or any other local url posssibility but get the same error

The dependencies in the project are:

```
   "behat/behat": "~3.0",

   "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^5.3",
```

I get the same slightly shorter error message when trying to run from within phpStorm.  similar questions which i've found all seem to more related to a live setup, is there anything else in Symfony there could be?...

Comment: What does your `behat.yml.dist` look like? You can also specify a base_url there, which might be what is causing the issue.

Comment: in that file it was also  

    `base_url: http://BASE_URL`  

...when replaced with my app's local url, this does give a different error when running a behat - as it gets to the point where there is a response code check and errors with eg    

`Current response status code is 404, but 200 expected. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ExpectationException)`  

( I don't think this is just the test doing it's job as it works for colleagues sharing the same code )